# Recommended way of using Gazebo with ROS Groovy

Tags: gazebo, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Simulators!

I'm trying to get my robot simulation working with Gazebo (currently 1.2.5) in ROS Groovy.

After I checked the ROS wiki, the Gazebosim docs and the Q&A here, I'm still confused what the actual recommended way of using Gazebo with ROS Groovy is.

More precisely:

- Which version(s) of Gazebo will be supported in/is recommended for Groovy?
- Do I have to start maintaining an extra SDF description of my robot? (If yes, is/will SDF supported in other parts of ROS, e.g. robot state publisher?)
- Are there Tutorials available for ROS users to get quickly up to speed?

There is already some related documentation out there, such as [installation instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install) and [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#ROS_Integration_2) with notes regarding ROS. So, it might be sufficient to put a brief note somewhere to point ROS users like me in the right direction (linking to the recommended installation instructions and tutorials).

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/782/recommended-way-of-using-gazebo-with-ros-groovy/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 129 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's some insight into our dev process:

1. We decide on a set of features and functionality for a new release, and internally choose a deadline.
2. Develop, debug, test, write documentation, etc.
3. Feature freeze a release branch, which means no new features may be added.
4. About a week later we code freeze, which means only critical bug fixes may be added.
5. About a week later we release Gazebo with both source and debian packages.

When the next release of ROS rolls around, a version of Gazebo is selected and included in ROS. This version of Gazebo is not the newest, nor the most heavily tested with ROS. We have likely already moved onto a new version of Gazebo and fixed a slew of bugs.

In the near future ROS will not pull in a version Gazebo. Instead it will use the default system install. Until this happens, the situation is slightly ugly.

Cutting to the chase...I would stick with a version of Gazebo that works for you.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-15**:
Thanks for the insight! I take from your answer, that the better way (especially regarding the future) would be moving to the standalone installation, which would currently be 1.3. But as long as I don't run into problems, I can also stick with the version distributed with ROS (currently 1.2.5).

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-15**:
In case my above comment is correct, what about adding this information somewhere (e.g. ROS wiki, Gazebo wiki)? Furthermore, do you have any suggestions/updates regarding the URDF/SDF issue? PS: Sorry for nagging! :-)

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-15**:
I've put the development steps here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Development_Process. I'm aiming to make a standalone version of SDF in the coming weeks. It'll be up to the ROS community to adopt it, nor not.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-01-15**:
This is a scary prospect for me.  Currently, my ROS Gazebo runs fine, but 1.3.1 standalone crashes on startup.